# Run-time Error 1004 Application defined and object error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with error 1004. Bug is somewhere in use of Paste function, but I do not know where.

```
For i = 0 To citac
If pole(i + 1) - pole(i) > 1 Then
thissheet.Range("E" & CStr(pole(i) + 1) & ":E" & CStr(pole(i + 1))).Copy
Else
thissheet.Range("E" & CStr(pole(i) + 1)).Copy
End If

    For j = 2 To thiswbk.Worksheets.Count
    thiswbk.Sheets(j).Range("A1:A100000").Clear

    If pole(i + 1) - pole(i) > 1 Then

    thiswbk.Sheets(j).Range("A1:A" & CStr(pole(i + 1) - pole(i))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Else
    **thiswbk.Sheets(j).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll**<-problem

    End If
    Next j

Next i
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you check whether the `Sheets(j)` is not locked?

Comment: Not locked.....

Comment: Change `Sheets(j)` with `Worksheets(j)`?

Comment: Just a question - do you have `On Error Resume Next` on the top of your code somewhere?

Comment: You need to Clear before you Copy as I think it clears the clipboard.

Comment: Problem was in Clear function - clipboard was cleared too...Thanks, SJR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in Clear function. This is a solve:

```
For j = 2 To thiswbk.Worksheets.Count
    thiswbk.Sheets(j).Range("A1:A100000").Clear
    Next j

For i = 0 To citac
If pole(i + 1) - pole(i) > 1 Then
thissheet.Range("E" & CStr(pole(i) + 1) & ":E" & CStr(pole(i + 1))).Copy
Else
thissheet.Range("E" & CStr(pole(i) + 1)).Copy
End If

    For j = 2 To thiswbk.Worksheets.Count

    If pole(i + 1) - pole(i) > 1 Then

    thiswbk.Worksheets(j).Range("A1:A" & CStr(pole(i + 1) - pole(i))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Else
    thiswbk.Worksheets(j).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    End If
    Next j

Next i
```